# I was asked to install an SSL .cert in my server, should I do this?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I am trying to connect to a company's internal API (I am working on a project for them). This company has an API that has an SSL certificate from Sectigo.

From what I have gathered is a pretty well known CA, but for some weird reason, if I make a `cURL` request or use Postman, an error returns stating that it cannot solve the SSL encryption.

The company has told me that this is usual in their projects and that they always solve this by sharing the .cert file, so you can add it to your trusted CA's or something like that.

I have never done that with SSL, and in case this is needed, it is going to be kind of complex due to the specifics of the project. I should state that I do trust the company and the cert myself, is the way this cert appears to be installed that makes me doubtful. I would prefer to avoid this, although maybe I am missing something.

Now, before answering them, I want to know if this is something that should be avoided or if this is normal and I just have never happened to find myself in the situation. I also find it weird that a well known CA is not in the default OS's trusted CAs list.

Any advice?

Comment: Some SSL certs are not signed by an OS trusted root certificate, and others need intermediate certs. If it's a work computer, just install it. If it's your equipment, then you need to define your own trust criteria for what certs you can or will install.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs It would need to be installed in a server. I do not doubt of the authenticity of the cert, so it is not a matter of trust, is just that I never came across this procedure and I had doubts of the security and viability of it.

Comment: Here's a link from GoDaddy explaining intermediate certificates. Administrative how-tos are more appropriate for Server Fault than here. https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-an-intermediate-certificate-868

Comment: @S.Dre It is a normal procedure for certificates that you don't have a trust chain to.

Comment: Oh, my bad @dave_thompson_085, certainly `Sectigo` with a `c`. Corrected in the OP, I'll try to answer the last part of your comment when I have the info, thanks.